# Global variable doesn't work inside django views

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I wanted to use some dummy data in my **Django** views to work with **templates**. When the **posts** variable is outside the home function all I'm getting is an empty body. Although when I move it inside everything displays as it should.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Kamil', 
        'title' : 'Post 1',
        
    }, 
    {
        'author': 'Tomek', 
        'title' : 'Post 2',
    }, 
]

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog_app/home.html', context)
```

Here is also my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
            <p>By {{ post.author }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make posts a **global** variable

```
global posts

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Kamil', 
        'title' : 'Post 1',
        
    }, 
    {
        'author': 'Tomek', 
        'title' : 'Post 2',
    }, 
]
```

Comment: it throws SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: sorry! I have updated my answer, please check. Global variables cannot be declared and defined at the same time. They are supposed to be declared and defined separately.

Comment: Omg i didnt realize i had function with the same name within this file